# yii: put jquery value in hidden text to be submitted

Tags: php, jquery, yii, autocomplete

Here is my code using autocomplete to fill out textbox:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'kube',
    'id' => 'country-chain',
    //'name'=>'country_chain',
    'source' => $this->createUrl('request/suggestCountry'),
    'options' => array(
        'delay' => 300,
        'minLength' => 2,
        'showAnim' => 'fold',
        'select' => "js:function(event, ui) {
            $('#id').val(ui.item.id);
            $('#Evaluation_provinsi').val(ui.item.provinsi);
            $('#Evaluation_kabupaten').val(ui.item.kabupaten);
            $('#Evaluation_kecamatan').val(ui.item.kecamatan);
            $('#Evaluation_desa').val(ui.item.desa);
            $('#Evaluation_nama').val(ui.item.nama);
            $('#Evaluation_usaha').val(ui.item.usaha);
            $('#Evaluation_anggota').val(ui.item.anggota);
            $('#Evaluation_ketua').val(ui.item.ketua);
            $('#Evaluation_alamat').val(ui.item.alamat);
            $('#Evaluation_id_pendamping').val(ui.item.id_pendamping);
            $('#Evaluation_pendamping').val(ui.item.pendamping);
            $('#Evaluation_tipe').val(ui.item.tipe);
        }"
    ),
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'size' => '40',
        'class' => 'span12',
        'placeholder' => 'Nama KUBE'
    ),
));
```

I want to submit `id_pendamping` as hidden text field using this

```
echo $form->hiddenField($model,'id_pendamping',array('value'=>$id_pendamping));
```

But I get nothing.

Please help me.

Comment: do you get the value if it's text field? also check are you getting value in ui.item.id_pendamping?

Comment: in normal textbox yes i do get all values, the problem is i want to hide id_pendamping in my view form. So i used hidden field to submit this value.

Comment: show your html content of hidden field.

Comment: <div class="form-control text-center">
          <input value="" name="Evaluation[id_pendamping]" id="Evaluation_id_pendamping" type="hidden" />. 
          <input name="yt0" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 50%;" type="submit" value="Create" />       
     </div> I want value="" filled with id_pendamping from jquery #Evaluation_id_pendamping.

Comment: all is looking perfect. can you show me live demo if any? also check in firebug or console.

Comment: fyi: id_pendamping come from other model, in this case i just want to make sure id_pendamping value are passing when i submit this form.

Comment: In your console hit this code : $('#Evaluation_id_pendamping').val(2); F12 for console.

Comment: have you found the solution?